# External site authentication

Tags: 7, users, database

I apologize if this has been asked many times before, but I'm wondering if anyone has a link to a good tutorial on implementing a working remote authentication system in Drupal 7.  I'm new to Drupal.

I've found various examples online, but the system for doing this seems to have changed substantially between Drupal 5 to 6 to 7.

I have a working system that will allow me to authenticate a user remotely and adds the user to my drupal installation.  However now I cant log in any Drupal only (eg the admin) as I get an error saying that the username is unknown since the code is looking for my admin username in the external system.

I get an unrecognised username error. The code is being executed for both an external and an internal user.

I know it's something simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [OpenID core module](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--openid--openid.module/7) is a good example of a module that authenticates users using an external site (which is a OpenID provider).

The most relevant code is contained in [openid_form_user_login_block_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--openid--openid.module/function/openid_form_user_login_block_alter/7), which alters the login block to allow users to log in using OpenID, [openid_login_validate()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--openid--openid.module/function/openid_login_validate/7), which is the validation handler for the login form, and [openid_user_insert()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--openid--openid.module/function/openid_user_insert/7), which calls [user_set_authmaps()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_set_authmaps/7), the function that allows to associate external user names to the user IDs present in the user table.

Answer (score 2):

I had success modifying the [Portal Plus Authentication](http://drupal.org/project/ppauth) module.

This module uses a SOAP web service to check if the user & password exist in the remote system and if so, creates/updates the user in the Drupal database. It also has some nice features such as the option to add a role to the user at login for the first time, or to not allow drupal-only members to log in.

I recommend looking at the source of this module, specially because it's small, simple and easy to understand (Drupal 6/7 versions available).